# How to implement a reliable UDP transport in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, wcf, udp

I'm looking for advises and directions on how to implement a reliable UDP transport in WCF.

I need to create an application where both client and server need to provide services to each other and WCF seems to me like a very good option. I'm new to WCF and I only know the very basics, yet. From what I've read, WCF duplex TCP channel creates a TCP connection from client-to-server and another one from server-to-client for callbacks and that's a problem for me, because clients are usually behind a firewall/router. I'm considering the use of UDP transport to avoid that problem, since UDP is connectionless, but I would need to implement a reliable connection-oriented UDP transport to accomplish what I need.

I've looked into the [custom UDP transport samples at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/transport-udp), but I still don't know exactly what is needed to implement a custom transport that would support basically the same functionality as an usual TCP transport, assuming I would already know how to implement the reliability stuff of UDP.

---

As possible alternatives for accomplishing what I need using the built-in TCP transport, I've read about long-polling, but that seems counterintuitive and seems to add unnecessary complexity to the whole thing. I'm open for suggestions about alternatives to the UDP approach, though.

Comment: I would think twice about using UDP just because you are probably gonna be behind firewalls. In my opinion using udp here will cause more trouble than asking for firewall exceptions...

Comment: @Dominik, Could you please elaborate more on what kind of problems could happen with using UDP in this situation? Thank you!

Comment: @A Silva, if you want to build something that transports data reliable you will have to build something that works like TCP. TCP ensures a lot of things (order of packages etc.). I'm pretty sure that WCF relies on a lot of those things (you will probably never find out what exactly WCF really needs). In fact you would have to implement TCP because otherwise i'm 99% sure WCF won't work properly (it will fail if packages are received in the wrong order etc.). That means you will practically build TCP but on top of UDP.

Comment: ... Without wanting to offend you but i'm sure you that your solution will be buggier than the official TCP implementations. In fact the only thing you accomplish with a lot of work and a probably not bugfree solution is to get around a stupid firewall...

Comment: @Dominik, I understand, it would be personally very hard for me to implement TCP functionality over UDP. However, assuming I would already have that done (for example, by using a well tested 3rd party library), I'm looking on how to implement it on WCF.

I think the firewall is a greater problem than it looks, in my case, because I don't want to ask users of my app to open a TCP port on their routers. It would be inconvenient for them and very hard for users that are not tech savy.

Comment: @A Silva, when they connect to your server they don't have to open their firewall. You will have to open yours because you are the listening part. You don't have to adjust your firewall just because you open www.google.com right? That's exactly the same.

Comment: @Dominik, this application requires the client to use services on the server and the server to use services on the client. A duplex TCP channel would be enough, I guess, but it then requires the server to connect to the client for the callbacks.

I don't even know if that's possible on WCF, but another solution I can think of is if I implement a custom duplex TCP channel that reuses the connection the client established with the server. I think ZeroC Ice library does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is great, while the UDP protocol is un-reliable natively. So WCF duplex channel are based on the TCP protocol.  as mentioned in the article,

> For the UDP transport, the only MEP that is supported is Datagram,
>   because UDP is inherently a "fire and forget" protocol.

As far as I know, if we want to ensure the reliability of UDP communication, the application layer protocol is supposed to finish Confirmation and timeout retransmission mechanism. That’s means that we should consider implementing reliable UDP transport at the application layer (at least not yet officially implemented). 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331599/What-s-new-in-WCF-4-5-UDP-transport-support
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/service-channel-listeners-and-channels